# Multiple URLs in a single JSON Hyperlilnk

Tags: hyperlink, json

I have a quick question about JSON HREF in SharePoint lists: Is it possible to trigger opening of 2 URLs in 2 new tabs by one hyperlink click? I tried some things like the one below, but they all failed...

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$URL1]",
    "href": "[$URL2]"
                }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance Nico

Comment: Nope. Sorry, it isn't possible in list formatting.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

You cannot create such hyperlink using JSON formatting which will open 2 URLs in 2 new tabs by one hyperlink click.

Comment: Please [accept this as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.